# Hyperledger Composer v0.19 is it possible to encrypt/decrypt assets' data in script file (lib/*.js)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

HLF v1.1 introduces the feature of encrypting and decrypting data on chaincode level. The enc/dec keys are passed to the chaincode through the
transient fields.

**Q: Is it possible to encrpt/decrypt assets' data in script file (lib/*.js) with composer v0.19?**

I've check the recent documentation of the composer and there is no information regarding encryption and decryption of the data written to the Ledger.

The only thing which is possible is actually the encryption/decryption on the application level which invokes transactions. This solution is quite useless since I have no chance to develop any business logic in script file (lib/*.js) on encrypted data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available in Composer. And it is not available through the (getNativeApi).

The recommendation is still to encrypt/de-crypt at the client application side.